# Why are my api calls for my Vue app being routed through some code in an unrelated dependancy, vue-query-builder?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, babeljs

I am building a Vue application and have installed tailwindcss-vue-query-builder, which is my own repackaging of vue-query-builder with some styling changes for my application. During some debugging of some api calls I noticed that vue-query-builder showed up in the stack trace of all my errors. It is a package used for building query objects and has nothing to do with making the actual api calls. Where would I start debugging this and figuring out why this is happening? Here is as example stack trace:

[Api call error stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1Y1G.png)

Here is the code referenced in the stack trace:

```
    // constructor polyfill
if (!USE_NATIVE) {
  // 25.4.3.1 Promise(executor)
  $Promise = function Promise(executor) {
    anInstance(this, $Promise, PROMISE, '_h');
    aFunction(executor);
    Internal.call(this);
    try {
      executor(ctx($resolve, this, 1), ctx($reject, this, 1)); // line 910 here
    } catch (err) {
      $reject.call(this, err);
    }
  };
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  Internal = function Promise(executor) {
    this._c = [];             // <- awaiting reactions
    this._a = undefined;      // <- checked in isUnhandled reactions
    this._s = 0;              // <- state
    this._d = false;          // <- done
    this._v = undefined;      // <- value
    this._h = 0;              // <- rejection state, 0 - default, 1 - handled, 2 - unhandled
    this._n = false;          // <- notify
  };
  Internal.prototype = __webpack_require__("dcbc")($Promise.prototype, {
    // 25.4.5.3 Promise.prototype.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)
    then: function then(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
      var reaction = newPromiseCapability(speciesConstructor(this, $Promise));
      reaction.ok = typeof onFulfilled == 'function' ? onFulfilled : true;
      reaction.fail = typeof onRejected == 'function' && onRejected;
      reaction.domain = isNode ? process.domain : undefined;
      this._c.push(reaction);
      if (this._a) this._a.push(reaction);
      if (this._s) notify(this, false);
      return reaction.promise;
    },
    // 25.4.5.1 Promise.prototype.catch(onRejected)
    'catch': function (onRejected) {
      return this.then(undefined, onRejected);
    }
  });
  OwnPromiseCapability = function () {
    var promise = new Internal();
    this.promise = promise;
    this.resolve = ctx($resolve, promise, 1);
    this.reject = ctx($reject, promise, 1);
  };
  newPromiseCapabilityModule.f = newPromiseCapability = function (C) {
    return C === $Promise || C === Wrapper
      ? new OwnPromiseCapability(C)
      : newGenericPromiseCapability(C);
  };
}
```

It appears to be a webpack poly fill for Promises, but I'm confused as to why the stack trace points towards vue-query-builder, and why a poly fill might be used. I'm only working on the newest versions of FF Dev Edition and Chrome. Any help is much appreciated.

Upon further investigation it looks like a Babel poly fill for Promises not webpack. It's used on all my Promises. Why would this be used when the browsers I'm using support Promises?

Comment: Solved. Vue-query-builder does not have the babel config file set to not use polyfills. As a library it shouldn't and let the main application deal with that. https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#polyfills-when-building-as-library-or-web-components. I added `useBuiltIns: false` to the babel config and re-published. Now my error stack is showing the es6.promise.js polyfill as part of the stack trace and not the vue-query-builder code.